# Is it a good practice to use abstract class an inner classes in C++

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I have a class that needs to maintain multiple (2 or 3 at the moment) contexts. These contexts are not visible outside the class. Currently I have a design as follows. Is it a good practice to use abstract class as inner classes in C++? If you have any alternatives, kindly suggest.

In the below example: The problem is, when the original Car class was written, the methods (bar1 and bar2) were written in the context of Sedan. Now I am extending the Car class by introducing a new car type (Hatchback). The algorithms in bar1 and bar2 are written for Sedan-type, and cannot be used for Hatch-back type. Unfortunately, I cannot change the existing Car class (i.e. constructor or method signatures). Therefore, I am introducing the Type class as in the example above.

Does my design approach makes sense? Please suggest better alternatives or potential problems in current design.

```
class Car {
public:
   explicit Car(/* sedan-type */) {
      // set context as Sedan
   }

   explicit Car(/* hatchback-type */) {
      // set context as Hatchback
   }

   void bar1() { context_type.bar1() };
   void bar2() { context_type.bar2() };

private:
   class Type {
      virtual void bar1() = 0;
      virtual void bar2() = 0;
   }
   class SedanType {
      void bar1() {}
      void bar2() {}
   }
   class HatchBackType {      
      void bar1() {}
      void bar2() {}
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could look into the pimpl idiom.

Comment: I believe nested (inner) classes should be avoided.  In the example you posted, the nested classes should be independent classes that derive from class Car.  Otherwise, users may see something like `Car::HatchbackType`, rather than `HatchBackCar`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a fine practice, especially if different classes have similarly named policies and you don't want to confuse them.  If you don't have a worry about that, then it sometimes it's simply less work to put them outside the class.  It is rather common as a Java idiom, though.

Usually you'd only see the base inner class, if it is abstract.  You *absolutely* should not have different constructors for `Car` based on them as arguments.  You aren't separating your concerns and you aren't making the policy [substitutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

```
class Base {
public:
  Base(SomeAbstractPolicy *policy);
  struct SomeAbstractPolicy {
    virtual ~SomeAbstractPolicy() {}
    virtual void stuff() = 0;
  };
};
```

Sometimes lazies will complain about [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) constructs like this.  Putting the concrete policies in the same header or as static helpers in the class can be a reasonable compromise.

```
class Base {
public:
  Base(SomeAbstractPolicy *policy);
  struct SomeAbstractPolicy {
    virtual ~SomeAbstractPolicy() {}
    virtual void stuff() = 0;
  };
  static SomeAbstractPolicy *CreateAwesomeConcretePolicy();
  static SomeAbstractPolicy *CreateSweetConcretePolicy();
};
```

You could take this a step further and use a named constructor.

```
class Base {
public:
  Base CreateAwesomeBase();
  Base CreateSweetBase();

private:
  struct SomeAbstractPolicy {
    virtual ~SomeAbstractPolicy() {}
    virtual void stuff() = 0;
  };

  Base(SomeAbstractPolicy *policy);
  SomeAbstractPolicy *policy;
};
```

Unit testing this is a lot harder, for what it's worth.

If you can't have one constructor based on your abstract policy, then the abstraction belongs in Car, not it the policy.  It is usually a simpler solution when you do make this sort of change.  A code smell for this is that you see methods with their entire body is a  branch on the type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer with well-illustrated examples.

Answer (score 0):

Why not still extend class `Car` and override the `bar1()` and `bar2()` methods. In their implementations you don't have to call your parent class's methods so you will still get what you want.

For example lets take the sedan car :

```
class SedanCar : public Car {
  public :
     void bar1() {// do algorithm for sedan};
     void bar2() {// do algorithm for sedan};
}
```

Now any instance of SedanCar with calls to `bar1()` or `bar2()` will execute the sedan implemenations.

Comment: My constraint is: the objects are created outside in other files/modules (which I don't want to touch) using "Car" class, and not SedanCar. So I don't want to modify the existing code as it's lot of change.

Comment: Well, in your current design how do you intend to pass the contexts of each car type without changing the existing objects creation ?

Comment: The old constructor passes the sedan type. All I have to do is, do the same and add a new constructor for the hatchback type. In that way, the new code/modules which is going to use/create hatchback-type "Car" objects can just use the new constructor. Also, all the old code using Sedan type works just fine w.o. modification.

Comment: Thanks for your input(s). I am sorry, it is a bit tricky situation and my text might not be articulating it well. Please ask questions if I am not clear enough.